# Proof that $ 2\sqrt{x_1x_2} \le x_1+x_2 $

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

We have
$$ x_1, x_2,...,x_n \ge 0 $$

and $$ P(n): x_1x_2....x_n \le \left(\frac{x_1+...+x_n}{n}\right)^{n} $$

I have to prove that P(2) is valid.

$$x_1 x_2 \le \left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)^{2} $$

I don't know how to achieve this, this is what I tried so far:

$$ \sqrt{x_1x_2} \le \frac{x_1+x_2}{2} $$

$$ 2\sqrt{x_1x_2} \le x_1+x_2 $$

Here, I don't know how to go further. Is this a good way proving this or am I completely wrong?

Comment: AM/GM${{{{}}}}$

Comment: You are assuming what you have to prove. How about looking at the difference of the two sides of your proposed inequality?

Comment: $(x_1 - x_2)^2 \geq 0$. The LHS is $x_1^2 - 2x_1 x_2 + x_2^2$. Add $4x_1 x_2$ to both sides to obtain $x_1^2 + 2x_1 x_2 + x_2^2 \geq 4x_1 x_2$. Simplify the LHS and divide by $4$.

Comment: @Bungo I don't see why $$ x_1^{2}+2x_1x_2+x_2^{2} \ge 4x_1x_2 $$ is valid when dividing both sides by 4 ?

Comment: @Blnpwr You can always divide both sides of an inequality by a positive number. For example, if $a \geq b$ then $a-b$ is nonnegative, hence so is $(a-b)/4 = a/4 - b/4$, and therefore $a/4 \geq b/4$.

Comment: @Bungo now I have $$ \frac{x_1^{2}}{4}+\frac{x_1x_2}{2}+ \frac{x_2^{2}}{4} \ge x_1x_2 $$ Is this right ?

Comment: You don't need to do it that way you can just go ahead and say that since $\sqrt{x_1^2+2x_1x_2+x_2^2}\geq \sqrt{4x_1x_2}$ you can also divide both sides to $2$ after taking root, keep in mind that this inequality also works in positive numbers that is why I didn't take the absolute value after taking root.

Comment: @Blnpwr Sure, now note that the LHS is equal to $(x_1^2 + 2x_1 x_2 + x_2^2)/4$, which equals $(x_1 + x_2)^2/4$, which is what you are trying to prove in $P(2)$.

Answer (score 5):

It's $$\left(\sqrt{x_1}-\sqrt{x_2}\right)^2\geq0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(a - b)^2 \ge 0$.  Expand and manipulate

Answer (score 0):

The important parts about the proof are already given in the answers up there. I want to share something different, geometrical actually (not that it works for a proof though) Consider a circle $OAB$ (the center is $T$) with a diameter $|AB|$ now inside the circle choose a point $P$ ($P\in|AB|$)such that $|AP|=x_1$ and $|BP|=x_2$ and then choose a point $K$ **on** the circle such that $<KPB=90^\circ$

As we know from Euclid's theorem $|KP|=\sqrt{x_1x_2}$ and as we know that if this segment $|KP|$ tends to the center $T$ it will be closer and closer to the radius which is $\dfrac{x_1+x_2}{2}$ so we can conclude that it is smaller or equal to the radius, Thus;

$$\sqrt{x_1x_2}\leq\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$$

As I've said this is completely partial, although fun If you draw the shape and see. This also works only for two variables.